# Регулярное выражение для получения номера телефона

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка вида:

```
Номер клиента: 1234567890<br>Вид заявки:
```

Номер может принимать вид не только как написано выше, но и есть варианты

```
+12345678901
+1(234) 567-89-00
1-234-567-89-00
1 234 567 89 00
```

Как составить регулярное выражение, чтобы вытягивался только номер, а остальное не учитывалось. В идеале нужно приводить номер к единообразию но пока это не выйдет. Обрезкой не выйдет т.к. начало номера может быть разное (окончание по знаку < обрезать можно но вот что дальше пока не могу придумать).

Comment: Извените немного не полностью вопрос поставил в начале строки может быть любой текст на кирилице и разные символы не только определенные слова. Пробывал ставить вместо слов выражение любые буквы от а-я не помогло.И странно то что на локале preg_replace выполняется нормально, а на сервере обрезать не хочет начал все равно остается текст "номер клиента" в базу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам следует разделить вытаскивание номера и его форматирование. Конечно, всё можно сделать и одной регуляркой, но это решение не будет выглядеть чисто.

Можно вытаскивать примерно такой регуляркой: `/Номер клиента: \+?([0-9-() ]+)/`, часть `\+?([0-9-() ]+)` которой совпадает с номером телефона, что может содержать плюсик в начале (а может и не содержать), а сам номер телефона может состоять из цифер, пробелов, дефисов и скобок. Примерно так:

```
$input_string = 'Номер клиента: +1(234) 567-89-00<br>Вид заявки:';
$phone_number = preg_replace('/Номер клиента: \+?([0-9-() ]+)/', '$1', $input_string);
```

Теперь этот номер надо отформатировать. Обычно номера телефонов приводят к числовому значению, поэтому лучше всего просто удалить лишние символы из номера с помощью функции [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.str-replace.php):

```
$clean_number = str_replace([' ', '-', '(', ')'], '', $phone_number);
echo $clean_number; // 12345678900
```

Если будете помещать номер телефона в базу данных, выбирайте какое-нибудь текстовое поле, иначе те номера, что начинаются с нуля, как верно подметил [@Miron](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/198591/miron), в дальнейшем могут быть некорректно обработаны. Старайтесь работать с номером телефона как со строкой, а не как с числом.

Comment: Удалять из номера телефона его форматирование можно только в том случае, если вам никогда и ни при каких обстоятельствах не нужно будет разделить номер телефона на код страны / города / оператора и т. п., иначе определить , например, код страны из цифр 12345678900 будет невозможно, так как коды стран, городов, мобильных операторов, сам номер телефона может состоять из разного кол-ва символов.

Comment: @Miron, автор вопроса сказал, что номера находятся в произвольном формате, так что форматирование может и вовсе отсутствовать. Да и данный вопрос, в принципе, решается функцией [`substr()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.substr.php), которую, разумеется, удобнее (точнее, разумнее) использовать на отфильтрованном номере.

Comment: Хорошо, но тогда, если номер начинается с нуля, предложенный вами вариант с (int)str_replace() обрежет ведущие нули, что тоже не есть хорошо. Хранить номера телефонов, которые записаны в произвольном формате - нельзя, ввиду возможности утери ведущего нуля.

Comment: @Miron, ай, а вы правы. Даже не думал, что существуют номера, начинающиеся с нуля. Исправил ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы приводить номер к единому образу следует пользоваться библиотеками для форматирования. Например, популярной библиотекой [`libphonenumber`](https://github.com/giggsey/libphonenumber-for-php):

```
$swissNumberStr = "0446681800";
$phoneUtil = \libphonenumber\PhoneNumberUtil::getInstance();
try {
    $swissNumberProto = $phoneUtil->parse($swissNumberStr, "CH");
    // Будет отображено "044 668 18 00"
    echo $phoneUtil->format($swissNumberProto, \libphonenumber\PhoneNumberFormat::NATIONAL);
} catch (\libphonenumber\NumberParseException $e) {
    var_dump($e);
}
```

Comment: А вы хорошо тестировали эту библиотеку? Что-то я сомневаюсь, что она сможет разобрать все возможные варианты ввода номера пользователем.

Comment: Естественно, это не золотая пуля, но она хороша в форматировании номеров. Я использовал порт libphonenumber для Python, который тоже сделан по принципам гугловой библиотеки, и она справлялась нормально. Конечно, перед отправкой номера библиотеке нужно провести хоть какую-то нормализацию данных, чтобы на выходе получать более-менее приемлемые результаты.

Comment: На мой взгляд "нормализировать" номера телефонов из разных стран просто невозможно, ввиду того, что нет единого стандарта для их записи. Лучше сразу при вводе обязать, заставить или ненавязчиво попросить пользователя ввести номер из 3-х частей: код страны, код оператора/города, сам номер.

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю автору вопроса, все же для начала привести базу номеров телефонов к единому виду, чтобы не хранить в БД некорректные номера. Если номера телефонов могут быть из разных стран, нужно обязательно хранить код страны отдельно от самого номера и кода оператора/города. Иначе могут возникнуть проблемы.

Если номер записан в международном формате, например так +12345678901 или так +1(234) 567-89-01, то по нему можно связаться с абонентом. Но что делать, если номер записан так: (234) 567-89-01 или вообще так 567-89-01? Дозвонится до абонента с таким номером будет очень сложно, если не сказать - невозможно. Хранить такие номера - бессмысленно, поэтому их лучше сразу удалить.

Никогда не храните номера телефонов, в виде числа. Связано это с тем, что если номер телефона будет начинаться с нуля(ей) при приведении его к типу int вы навсегда потеряете ведущие нули. Номера телефонов нужно хранить исключительно в виде строки (string).

И еще один важный момент - стандарты по нумерации телефонов абонентов в разных странах могут существенно отличаться, и поэтому, номера лучше хранить как 3 разные части: код страны, код города/оператора, номер телефона.