# Регулярное выражение и обход массива

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Почему регулярка не проходит?

```
// Правильные: 
$correctNumbers = [ 
  '84951234567',  '+74951234567', '8-495-1-234-567', 
  ' 8 (8122) 56-56-56', '8-911-1234567', '8 (911) 12 345 67', 
  '8-911 12 345 67', '8 (911) - 123 - 45 - 67', '+ 7 999 123 4567', 
  '8 ( 999 ) 1234567', '8 999 123 4567'
];

// Неправильные: 
$matches = [];
$incorrectNumbers = [
  '02', '84951234567 позвать люсю', '849512345', '849512345678', 
  '8 (409) 123-123-123', '7900123467', '5005005001', '8888-8888-88',
  '84951a234567', '8495123456a', 
  '+1 234 5678901', /* неверный код страны */
  '+8 234 5678901', /* либо 8 либо +7 */
  '7 234 5678901' /* нет + */
];
$regexp = '/^((-| )?[()]?){1,}(\+7|8)((-| )?[()]?){1,}((-| )?[()]?){1,}[0-9]((-| )?[()]?){1,}[0-9]((-| )?[()]?){1,}[0-9]((-| )?[()]?){1,}[0-9]((-| )?[()]?){1,}[0-9]((-| )?[()]?){1,}[0-9]((-| )?[()]?){1,}[0-9]((-| )?[()]?){1,}[0-9]((-| )?[()]?){1,}[0-9]((-| )?[()]?){1,}[0-9]$/g';
foreach($correctNumbers as $value) {
    echo "{$value} -\n";
    if(preg_match_all($regexp, $value)) {
        echo $value;
        echo "verno\n";
    } else {
        echo "ne verno {$value}\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Лучше для каждого допустимого формата создать свою регулярку, чтобы не путаться. Даже если починить вашу, то ее никто потом, включая вас, не сможет поддерживать. А еще лучше подходить с другого конца: например, как я описал в [этом ответе](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/595572/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0/595584#595584).

Answer (score 0):

preg_match_all() и так делает "\g", так что данный модификатор вам не нужен:

```
$regexp = '/^((-| )?[()]?){1,}(\+7|8)((-| )?[()]?){1,}((-| )?[()]?){1,}[0-9]((-| )?[()]?){1,}[0-9]((-| )?[()]?){1,}[0-9]((-| )?[()]?){1,}[0-9]((-| )?[()]?){1,}[0-9]((-| )?[()]?){1,}[0-9]((-| )?[()]?){1,}[0-9]((-| )?[()]?){1,}[0-9]((-| )?[()]?){1,}[0-9]((-| )?[()]?){1,}[0-9]$/';
```